# If there is such a function in a variadic template?

Tags: c++, c++20

for example there is such a template

```
template<class ... Types> void f(Types ... args);

f();       // OK: args contains no arguments
f(1);      // OK: args contains one argument: int
f(2, 1.0); // OK: args contains two arguments: int and double
```

and I want to do so in it

```
template<class ... T>
void f2(T... args) {
  // option 1
  // > hello // world // human
  std::cout <<(args / ...);

  // option 2
  // > hello // world
  std::cout <<((args / ...) and -1 args); // ../
}
```

in the example, option 2
We are concatenating the `Hello` and `world` string and at the same time not using the `human`, since we don't need it yet.

if it is possible of course

```
f2("hello", "world", "human");
```

then

get one less argument inside the function to use it inside the function

For this call:

```cpp
f2("A", "b", 12);
```

Expected result should be equivalent to this:

```
std::cout << "A";
std::cout << "b";

// no statement or different action for: std::cout << 12;
```

and if possible without arrays and recursions
if there is no such functionality, then write that it is not there.

Comment: You want to apply something to all the arguments? Such as print each one in turn?

Comment: yes I want to get each argument inside the function separately, or by plus or mnus one

Comment: although I write when calling 3 arguments, inside the function I want to use 2 arguments in the if condition and in the second condition I will use 3 arguments

Comment: @DoydgonK. after your comment under my answer, your question become more clear. So I've improved your question (so anyone could understood it) and I've found respective duplicate.

Comment: I think the duplicate is outdated, it was written 7 years ago, and there is a lot of code :)

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
template<bool condition, typename T>
void printIf(T&& arg)
{
    if constexpr (condition) std::cout << arg;
}

template<size_t...indexes, class ... T>
void printAllButLastHelper(std::integer_sequence<size_t, indexes...> v, T&&... args) {
    (printIf<sizeof...(args) - 1 != indexes>(args), ...);
}

template<class ... T>
void f2(T&&... args) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    printAllButLastHelper(
        std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, sizeof...(args)>{}, 
        std::forward<T>(args)...);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3dojcd